# Calculating the velocity needed to make a distance in the horizontal with a given height and no upward motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

In 1780, in what is now referred to as "Brady's Leap," Captain Sam Brady of the U.S. Continental Army escaped certain death from his enemies by running over the edge of the cliff above Ohio's Cuyahoga River, which is confined at that spot to a gorge. He landed safely on the far side of the river. It was reported that he leapt 22ft across while falling 20ft 
[image]

Now how do I calculate the minimum speed needed to make the "jump"?

Comment: I actually rather like this question, though it is at present too homeworksy for the site. Try to ask more directly about methods and concepts instead of the specific problem you were set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you consider his angle at which he "jumped". Assuming he just ran straight off, we can simply just use our kinematic equations for both x and y. First let us do it for y because this will tell us how long he was in the air. First note note that he has no angle $v_{y0}=0$

$\begin{align}y=&y_{0}+v_{y0}t+\tfrac{1}{2}at^2\\\ y-y_{0}=&(0)t+\tfrac{1}{2}gt^2 \\\ 2(y-y_{0})g=&t^2 \longrightarrow t=\sqrt{\frac{2(6m-0m)}{9.8m/s^2}} \approx 1.22s\end{align}$

Now that we have the time that he is in the air we can apply it to the x direction kinematics equation. This is because there is no acceleration in the x (horizontal) direction because gravity is purely vertical (or downwards). Since we know how far he must go in the x direction we do

$\begin{align}y=&x_{0}+v_{x0}t+\tfrac{1}{2}at^2\\\ x-x_{0}=&v_{x0}t+\tfrac{1}{2}(0)t^2\\\ (x-x_{0})/t=&v_{x0} \longrightarrow v_{x0}=(6.5m-0m)/1.22s \approx 5.5m/s\end{align}$

This is really fast! Note that I converted feet to meters ($22ft \approx 6.5m$ and $20ft \approx 6m$)

Comment: No problem! But beware: Never assume any of these answers are correct. Make sure you can justify them, and that you could solve this problem (and similar ones) in a test situation.

Comment: @jerk_dadt It's nice of you to provide an answer, but as you are aware (judging by your comment), providing fully worked out solutions to elementary exercises such as this is most likely not in the best interest of the reader. Furthermore, it encourages others to see if they can get their homework done for them on this website too. Therefore, we usually try to refrain from doing this (no offense to you personally).

Comment: @danu Yes, I agree. I get carried away sometimes. How should I post an "answer" without posting the "answer"?   And no offense taken. I will refrain from providing solutions to elementary questions like this from now on

Comment: @jerk_dadt what I try to usually do is post a short comment suggesting what kind of formula to look for. Or ask a question like: what variable will you need? What formula's do you know that would allow you to find it? etc.

Comment: @danu ahh I see. So don't actually post an answer but guide them with questions in the comments. That is definitely more useful. Thanks!